# Ruby on Rails: Join Tables Concept

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have been out of the coding game for a while and recently decided to pick up rails. I have a question about the *concept* of Join tables in rails. Specifically:

1) why are these join tables needed in the database?

2) Why can't I just JOIN two tables on the fly like we do in SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A join table allows a clean linking of association between two independent tables.  Join tables reduce **data duplication** while making it easy to **find relationships in your data** later on.

E.g. if you compare a table called `users`:

```
| id | name     |
-----------------
| 1  | Sara     |
| 2  | John     |
| 3  | Anthony  |
```

with a table called `languages`:

```
| id| title    |
----------------
| 1 | English  |
| 2 | French   |
| 3 | German   |
| 4 | Spanish  |
```

You can see that both truly exist as separate concepts from one another.  Neither is subordinate to the other the way a single *user* may have many *orders*, (where each order row might store a unique *foreign_key* representing the `user_id` of the user that made it).

When a language can have many users, and a user can have many languages -- we need a way to join them.

We can do that by creating a join table, such as `user_languages`, to store every link between a *user* and the *language(s)* that they may speak.  With each row containing every matchup between the pairs:

```
| id | user_id | language_id |
------------------------------
| 1  | 1       | 1           |
| 2  | 1       | 2           |
| 3  | 1       | 4           |
| 4  | 2       | 1           |
| 5  | 3       | 1           |
```

With this data we can see that Sara (user_id: 1) is trilingual, while John(user_id: 2) and Anthony(user_id: 3) only speak English.

By creating a join table in-between both tables to store the linkage, we preserve our ability to make powerful queries in relation to data on other tables. For example, with a join table separating `users` and `languages` it would now be easy to find every `User` that speaks `English` or `Spanish` or both.

But where join tables get even more powerful is when you add new tables.  If in the future we wanted to link `languages` to a new table called `schools`, we could simply create a new join table called `school_languages`.  Even better, we can add this join table without needing to make any changes to the `languages` SQL table itself.

As Rails models, the data relationship between these tables would look like this:

```
User --> user_languages <-- Language --> school_languages <-- School
```

By default every school and user would be linked to Language using *the same language_id(s)*

This is powerful.  Because with two join tables (`user_languages` & `school_languages`) now referencing the same unique `language_id`, it will now be easy to write queries about how either relates.  For example we could find all schools who speak the language(s) of a user, or find all users who speak the language(s) of a school.  As our tables expand, we can ride the joins to find relations about pretty much anything in our data.

**tl;dr:**  Join tables preserve relations between separate concepts, making it easy to make powerful relational queries as you add new tables.